# Prism Inheriting from ViewModelBase vs BindableBase

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms application using the Prism template pack the project gets created with a `MainPageViewModel` that inherits from `ViewModelBase`

Later I create and an additional View and ViewModel say for ChatPage. This `ChatPageViewModel`inherits from `BindableBase`not `ViewModelBase` as generated by the Add New dialog.

I'd like to use ViewModelBase in all my View(Models) ViewModelBase inherits from `ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible`

I try and change the new `ChatPageViewModel :  BindableBase` to `ChatPageViewModel : ViewModelBase` but the constructor gets a red squiggly error; 
*Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'navigationService' of 'ViewModelBase.ViewModelBase(INavigationService)'*

I see in App.xaml.cs    that `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();` is implemented differently than the other pages `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ChatPage, ChatPageViewModel>();`

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingsPage, SettingsPageViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ChatPage, ChatPageViewModel>();

    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IXpdSettings, XpdSettings>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMqttDataService, MqttDataService>();
}
```

Is there a way I can inherit from ViewModelBase? Could / should it be implemented in the XamarinForms Prism templating?

Comment: So you want to create a Template in Visual studio that makes `ViewModelBase` as the base class View models your create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is contained in my question. See the syntax that the MainPageViewModel (that was created by the initial project creation dialog) uses - where MainPageViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase unlike subsequent pages created with Add New dialog that inherit from BindableBase. For instance ChatPageViewModel inheriting from ViewModelBase rather than BindableBase.

```
public class ChatPageViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private IXpdSettings _xpdsettings;
    public ChatPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IXpdSettings xpdSettings)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = "Mqtt Chat";
        _xpdsettings = xpdSettings;
    }
}
```